# How to update imports when they change location

Tags: go, package

I see that in Go you can import packages directly from Github like:

```
import "github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc"
```

I understand that the path I am seeing in import line is not an URL, but only the path the package is located in (normally relative to $GOROOT/src/pkg or $GOPATH/src). So the package heredoc is most probably located in the directory $GOPATH/src/github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc.

Now let's say that the package developer decided to migrate the code repo to Bitbucket. So now the library URL is `bitbucket.com/muchMoreCoolerName/heredoc`. He also added some new features to the code repo.

My question is how will you get the updated code?

The only solution I can think of is changing all the imports to new URL and doing `go get` again. But changing the code for library update seems a little inconvenient.

Comment: Yes, updating the imports line is the answer. Depending on the host where the original was hosted, a redirect may be put in place, to allow both names to work simultaneously. Typically, this will only work for a rename on a single platform (i.e. `github.com/foo/bar` to `github.com/foo/baz`), though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use go get and then import, there is no way around it, you will have to update the import paths to get the new code. However, if you use [vendoring](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules_and_vendoring)(a technique to keep your dependency with your code and also distribute it with them) you would be isolated from that move at least until you update. When you want to update, you could use a vendor functionality to keep the old import path but to sync with the other repo.

Frankly, I'd still use vendoring in anyway and just do a search and replace for the old import path when I decide to update, this is not that hard.

**EDIT** You can also use [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) to manage dependencies if you haven't transitioned to modules yet.